# MVC4 Filtering with checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have created create function in my controller which display all genres in checkoxes like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var db = new MainDatabaseEntities();            
    var viewModel = new ANIME
    {
        GENRES = db.GENRES.Select(c => new { ID_GE = c.ID_GE, GENRE = c.GENRE, isSelected = false }).ToList().Select(g => new GENRES
        {
            ID_GE = g.ID_GE,
            GENRE = g.GENRE,
            isSelected = false
        }).ToList()                        
    };
     return View(viewModel);       
}
```

View:

```
@model AnimeWeb.Models.ANIME

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="lefttablecontent" id="top">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_AN)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                Original title
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TITLE_OR)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TITLE_OR)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                English title
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TITLE_EN)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TITLE_EN)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                Genres
            </div>
            <div class="editor-list">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GENRES)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GENRES)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="righttablecontent" id="top">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}

}
```

EditorTemplate for Genres:

```
@model AnimeWeb.Models.GENRES

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_GE)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GENRE)
<table>
<tr>
<td class=" right">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.isSelected)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.isSelected, Model.GENRE)
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like to display the same template with all genres and use it for filtering in index, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int? page)
{
    using (var db = new MainDatabaseEntities())
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        var anime = from s in db.ANIME.Include("GENRES")
                       select s;

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(anime.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<AnimeWeb.Models.ANIME>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
{
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
}
</p>
@foreach (var item in Model)                //
{                                           //
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.GENRES);  // I'm not sure about this line
}                                           //
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Anime
    </th>
    <th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(item.TITLE_OR, "Details", new { id = item.ID_AN })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

When I try to display it with @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.GENRES) it displays only genres that are selected within each anime but I need all genres to filter with them. I'm not even sure is this a good way to make it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be as simple as passing the checkboxes checked as a filter to your data querying.

Comment: I've Edited first post to make problem more clear